# what is Nhoodsize[] in Houghpeaks?

Tags: image-processing, hough-transform

I have an image after preprocessing and done with Hough transform to determine the `(rho, theta)`. For finding the peaks, the statement `Nhoodsize []`, what actually determines and what is `[M N]`, two element vectors denotes?

For example:

```
[H, theta, rho] = hough(image)
peaks = houghpeaks(H, 20, 'NHoodSize', [19 19])
```

Answer (score 1):

Google "NHoodSize", click the first hit, read

https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghpeaks.html?refresh=true&requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

> 'NHoodSize' — Size of suppression neighborhood smallest odd values
>   greater than or equal to size(H)/50 (default) | two-element vector of
>   positive odd integers Size of suppression neighborhood, specified as a
>   two-element vector of positive odd integers. The suppression
>   neighborhood is the neighborhood around each peak that is set to zero
>   after the peak is identified.
>
> Data Types: double

According to the reference documentation you can suppress a neighbourhood around a detected peak. This means that you get rid of lines which are very similar to your peak line.